# CentOS 7 ignores saved_entry in grubenv

Tags: centos7, grub2

I recently updated my kernel, but the system keeps booting into the old one. I checked /boot/grub2/grubenv and the only entry is saved_entry pointing to my new kernel. However, whenever I reboot it always boots straight into the old kernel. Any ideas why grub2 would be ignoring the 'saved_entry' in the grubenv?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there was an error creating the grub2 entry, I had the same problem on a few of our CentOS servers recently. You could try creating the grub entry like this as a workaround:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

And reboot.